# Treeview select event is not firing in kendo ui

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-treeview

I have a treeview defined like

```
$("#treeview").kendoTreeView({
  dataSource:homogenous,
  dataBound: function(e){
       $("#treeview").data("kendoTreeView").select(".k-item:first");
 },
  select: function(){
     alert('selectd');
 }
});
```

Initially the treeview is selecting. But it is not getting the alert of `select`. But when we selecting the node it is getting the alert. How should i get rid of them.

Comment: Kendo treeview does not fire 'select' event onLoad by default. So you might have a script that's triggering it. What are you trying to acheive here?

Comment: initially i want to load a page based on the selected value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The select method won't fire the select event. You can however use the trigger method to fire any event:

```
dataBound: function(e){
   $("#treeview").data("kendoTreeView").select(".k-item:first");
   $("#treeview").data("kendoTreeView").trigger("select", { 
      node: $("#treeview .k-item:first")[0] 
   });       
},
```

Comment: Yah it works. And i have an another issue here. I am defining this in databound event and when we expand the treeview then also the databound event is firing. How can i get rid of this

Comment: You can do it only once by attaching the dataBound event handler using the one method:  treeView.one("dataBound", function() { /* rest of the code */ }); Call this after the treeview is initialized.