# how to trigger "Event" of kendo tree view?

Tags: javascript, jquery, .net, kendo-ui, kendo-treeview

---

1. we have js function "test" which is calling when we select any node from treeview.

2)now we are manually selecting node from js where we need,

this function ("Test") is not calling automatically as it should be called cause we have select node from js after all.

what we can do so this function will call as it working while anyone select node by mouse click.

we need help like this Is anything treeview.trigger('select'); ***

```
 public TreeViewBuilder C#funtionRobindTreeView(TreeViewBuilder builder)
    {
        TreeViewBuilder treeViewBuilder = builder;
        builder.Name(Id);
        builder.Items(treeView => objectdata.ToTreeItem(treeView));
        builder.Events(x => x.Select("Test"));
        builder.LoadOnDemand(true);
        return builder;
    }
```

js function

```
function Test(e) {
// called when we select any node using mouse click.
}};
```

Comment: when we select any node from js tree view event should be called.

Comment: have a look at the question and this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/16948666/493557